# Seek string within strings

Tags: prolog

I have an arbitrarily entered sequence of symbols, for example `progressive` and must determine whether it contains an entered sequence of symbols, for example `progress`.
My idea is to break the strings into lists of letters and compare lists.

```
'break'(Str,L):-'name'(Str,L1),'change'(L1,L).
'change'([],[]).
'change'([X|T],[S|T1]):-'name'(S,[X]),'change'(T,T1).

'break'(progressive,X).
X = [p, r, o, g, r, e, s, s, i|...].
```

But I have no idea how to break both words and to compare lists.

Examples of working program:

```
contain([progressive, progress]).   - Yes.
contain([progressive, progrev]).    - No.
```

Comment: Just an aside, you don't need single quotes around all of your functor names if they start with a lower case letter and don't have spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to put predicate names in quotation marks (unless you use spaces or some other non-alphabet characters, but usually you shouldn't do it).

And it's better to use ISO-standard `atom_codes` instead of `name`.

Here is a somewhat high-level implementation of what you want:

```
contain(X, Y) :-
    atom_codes(X, Xcodes),
    atom_codes(Y, Ycodes),
    append(_, End, Xcodes),
    append(Ycodes, _, End).
```

Test run (I use `contain(progressive, progress).` instead of `contain([progressive, progress]).` given in your example because it makes more sense to me. If you need to conform the example exactly, just change the head of the predicate `contain(X, Y)` to `contain([X, Y])`):

```
?- contain(progressive, progress).
true 

?- contain(progressive, progrev).
false.
```

Comment: Sergey, i'm sorry, I made a mistake. In my laborotory a have prolog for slackware... I can't to use predicate atom_codes:(

Comment: @user3633791 does your Prolog have something else that's like `atom_codes`? Can you look at the documentation for atom processing?

Comment: @lurker, probably not, so I imagined a partition in the following form:
'break'(Str,L):-'name'(Str,L1),'change'(L1,L).
'change'([],[]).
'change'([X|T],[S|T1]):-'name'(S,[X]),'change'(T,T1).

Comment: @user3633791 Just change all 'atom_codes' to 'name'.

Comment: @Sergey, has 'append' some alternatives?

Comment: @user3633791 if your system doesn't have built-in append, it's not hard to implement it. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Lists#The_append_predicate or just google 'append prolog' for 2-lines definition.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko. Sergey, good day! I have some trouble with this task..Now, i must entered for example contain(progressive,prgre) - Yes. Ask me please, how i can realize this task?

Answer (score 4):

I think a better solution would be to use [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5: it's ISO approved and provides much more functionality for text analysis. An example of usage

```
9 ?- sub_atom('swi-prolog', _,_,_, o).
true ;
true ;
false.

10 ?- sub_atom('swi-prolog', N,_,_, o).
N = 6 ;
N = 8 ;
false.
```